# Hot reloading with JAX-RS

Tags: java, servlets, jax-rs, netty, grizzly

I want to get a development experience like I get with [Play! framework](http://www.playframework.org/) with JAX-RS (with [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/) for example). More specifically I want to use some kind of background compilation and run the compiled code immediately so that I have almost no waiting time.

My first attempt was to use NetBeans background compilation and Maven with plug-ins for Tomcat and Jetty which are restarting the application in the running container. But restarting took too long. I'm wondering if I need to restart the application if code changed or if something like [Grizzly](http://grizzly.java.net/) or [Netty](http://www.jboss.org/netty) instead of a Servlet container would help.

Any ideas how to get fast reloads with JAX-RS?

Answer (score 3):

Try this, 
you need to add the dependencies. It uses [jreloader](http://code.google.com/p/jreloader/) (open source).
[ant archetype](http://code.google.com/p/ant-archetype/)

**Edit:**
People are still visiting this post after two years. Now there's a complete alternative for hot reloading and the project is active again http://dcevm.github.io/

You may need to use this as well https://github.com/HotswapProjects/HotswapAgent

Comment: jreloader looks very interesting!

Comment: javeleon is closed source, and doesn't support application servers. On top of that, the support is minimal. You may send a question and get an answer after around 9 month. You can have a baby in the mean while !

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at gretty: https://github.com/groovypp/gretty
It should work with jersey and you should see fast runtime reloads.

Answer (score 1):

JRebel does this: http://zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/

Comment: JRebel provides integration with a number of JAX-RS implementations - Jersey, CXF, RESTEasy, RESTlet